# How do I configure Publication Types?

Tags: 2013

We can set Types for Publications such as:

- `Content`
- `Web`
- `Mobile`

This lets us filter them in the CME.

I tried adding a new type by editing `%TRIDION_HOME%\Tridion\config\Tridion.ContentManager` in notepad and adding within `<publicationTypes>`:

```
<add id="1030" name="Define" titleResource="lblDefinePublicationType"/>
```

I cleared browser cache and tried an IIS reset, but don't see changes in the publication type drop-down or filter.

**Should I be able to configure then see a new type in the Publication Type drop-down? Am I missing a step?**

Notes in the config included:

```
<!-- 
Constraints: 
  1) id and name attribute is unique. 
  2) id > 1024. Numbers below 1024 are reserved.
  3) titleResource is optional. if titleResource is not provided
     then the value specified in name will be used as PublicationType.Title
-->
```

I also tried: `<add id="1030" name="Define"/>` in case I'm missing a label for the new type--not sure where they might be defined though.

This is specifically on a Windows 2012 machine with SDL Tridion 2013; 2011 seems similar but was missing a note reserving certain publication types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have edited Tridion.ContentManager.Config, which is Core configuration, but restarted IIS, which is CME playground. You need to reboot machine, or restart COM+ application and TCMServiceHost service to apply changes.

Comment: COM+ is not used in SDL Tridion 2013; it will either be available for Content Porter or backward compatibility or for licensing

Comment: Check your glasses :)

Comment: Ah, *Editors* like CME and Experience Manager "live" on the IIS side. I see how IIS is separate from the Content Management System.