# How can I add custom Publication Type

Tags: cme, web8.5

Can I add my custom Publication Types? How can I do it in Web 8.5?
I searched in Administration, Core Service but can't find anything. Can anybody help me with this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed add your own custom Publication Types. Simply edit the "publicationTypes" section of Tridion.ContentManager.config in a text editor and add your own.

As indicated by the comments in the file, you need to choose an ID that is greater than 1024 as anything below that is reserved by the system.

For example:

```
<publicationTypes>
   ....
   <add id="1025" name="Custom Publication Type" />
</publicationTypes>
```

Comment: Ah! you beat me 37secs

Answer (score 2):

You can add this custom **Publication Type** in **[Tridion-Install-Home]\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config** in the **publicationTypes** section

And Restart the SDL services and IIS SDL Tridion AppPools to see the new publication type list should appear in that drop-down.

I hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: I think the Service Host restart is needed per https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/660/46. I'm not sure if an IIS reset is specifically needed.